# How to show a pop up in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I need to show a pop-up in chrome extension. Presently the pop-up is showing in a new window when the extension icon is clicked.

What I need is that when I click on the extension a popup window should be seen just below the extension icon. Just like [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/#user_interface) (please check the pop-up in this link).

My pop-up window(userinfo.html) asks for a login with username and password. When the user enters both username and password, and logins, the pop-up should be closed and when the user again clicks on the extension icon, it should navigate to a website. How can I do this?
Here is my background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 if(!localStorage.username){
   chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
    popup: "userinfo.html"
   });
 }
 else
   //navigate to website
});
```

In this way, I show my pop-up. When the user clicks on the icon for the first time after installation the pop-up appears. Otherwise, it navigates to a website. Now my problem is that when I click twice on the icon only, the pop-up appears. The second problem is that after I enter the username and password and click login the pop-up closes, which is fine. When I clicked again on icon actually it should navigate to the website, but in my code it again shows pop up. When I reload the extension, it works correctly. Why is it like that? please help me.
There is a file named userinfo.html, which should be shown as a pop-up. How can I do this? Please help me.

Comment: By the way why do you browser_action defined twice?

Comment: When i defined twice only i got what i wanted that's why

Comment: Please do not keep changing the question in itself. People who have answered the original question are going to look like fools for no reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In browser action, you should include default_popup value which points to the HTML file to be rendered as popup. In your case it is userinfo.html.

```
"browser_action": 
     {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
```

More information here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/

Comment: I have put your code,but what I need is that for the first time when the user clicks the extension icon,he should see the pop up window asking for username and password.When he enters the username and password and clicks login,the pop up should be closed.The next time when he clicks the icon it should navigate to a website.how can i do this?please help me

Comment: You should look into setPopup method and chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener on the page I mentioned in the answer. Once you are done with the login in popup, remove the popup from browserAction and keep the listener in the code which will have the code to open a new tab with your website.

Comment: yeah exactly i was trying set popup method.But what happens is that,even if the user logins,and then again click on the extension icon, the pop up window is again shown.Once he enters his name and password on the pop up window and clicks login.then the pop up should no show anymore